# \seq_push and \seq_pop functions behaving badly, undoubtedly due to misuse

Tags: expl3

For my own good reasons I am loading `\param_seq` with an array of parameters, then want to transfer the content of `\param_seq` to `\aux_seq` by popping `\param_seq`, storing the popped item temporarily in `\aux_tl`, then pushing  `\aux_tl` on to `\aux_seq`. After two cycles of popping and pushing I can already see things go awry; for some reason `\aux_seq` has as many copies of the last popped item as there were cycles, and `\param_seq` now has not lost the popped items but had them replaced with copies of the last popped. Not the kind of shenanigans one would expect from a pair of stacks. What am I doing wrong?
I should add that in actual practice I am doing different things to different parameters, hence the case clause.

```
\documentclass{minimal}
%-----------------------------
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{amsmath}
%=============================
\ExplSyntaxOn
\tl_new:N \output_tl
\tl_new:N \aux_tl
\seq_new:N \params_seq
\seq_new:N \aux_seq
\int_new:N \index_i
%-----------------------------
\NewDocumentCommand\myFunction{O{,} m}{\myFunction_build:nn {#1}{#2}}
  \cs_new:Npn \myFunction_build:nn #1 #2 
    {
    \tl_clear:N \output_tl 
    \seq_clear:N \params_seq 
    \seq_set_split:Nnn \params_seq { #1 } { #2 }
    \seq_pop_left:NN \params_seq \aux_tl
    \tl_use:N \aux_tl \\
    \seq_push:Nn \aux_seq \aux_tl
    \seq_pop_left:NN \params_seq \aux_tl
    \tl_use:N \aux_tl \\
    \seq_push:Nn \aux_seq \aux_tl 
    \int_set:Nn \index_i { 0 }
    \seq_map_inline:Nn \aux_seq 
      {
      \int_incr:N \index_i
      \int_case:nnTF {\index_i}
        {
                    {1} {\tl_put_right:Nn \output_tl {##1,\c_space_tl}}
                    {2} {\tl_put_right:Nn \output_tl {##1,\c_space_tl}}
                    {3} {\tl_put_right:Nn \output_tl {##1,\c_space_tl}}
                    {4} {\tl_put_right:Nn \output_tl {##1,\c_space_tl}}
        }
        {}
        {}
      }
    \text{contents\, of\, aux\, sequence\,after\,two\,pushes:\, } \tl_use:N \output_tl \\
    \int_set:Nn \index_i { 0 }
    \seq_map_inline:Nn \params_seq  
      {
      \int_incr:N \index_i
      \int_case:nnTF {\index_i}
        {
                    {1} {\tl_put_right:Nn \output_tl {##1,\c_space_tl}}
                    {2} {\tl_put_right:Nn \output_tl {##1,\c_space_tl}}
                    {3} {\tl_put_right:Nn \output_tl {##1,\c_space_tl}}
                    {4} {\tl_put_right:Nn \output_tl {##1,\c_space_tl}}
        }
        {}
        {}
      }
    \text{contents\, of\, params\, seq\,after\,two\,pops:\, } \tl_use:N \output_tl \\
    }
\ExplSyntaxOff
%=======================================
\begin{document}
\noindent
\textbf{Function call:} \verb+\myFunction{1,2,3,4,5}+\\
\textbf{Disappointing result:} \\
\myFunction{1,2,3,4,5}\\
\end{document}
```

Comment: as a side note: please **follow the naming scheme**! It should be `\myFunction_build` -> `\neuwirth_myFunction_build`, `\output_tl` -> `\l_neuwirth_output_tl`, `\params_seq` -> `\l_neuwirth_params_seq`, `\index_i` -> `\l_index_int` etc. You can choose other prefix than `neuwirth`, but you have to use a prefix!

Comment: @yo It may seem I misname my variables out of spite, but this is not the case. Apart from section 3 in the expl3 document, what else do I need to study to get the naming right? Looking forward to your input. Thanks

Comment: I think it's covered there pretty well, especially in §3.2. It's just not explained there that for you (or me or any other L3 user), `module` is something that is specific to their works. Also, module names intended to be used by the general public should be registered with the team, to avoid name clashes.

Comment: @yo I have been bemoaning the fact that the l3 documents talk about local and global in a few places, but nowhere seem to say how to set the scope for a variable. Is the mechanism in the naming? For example, does the `l_` in `\l_neuwirth_output_tl` make this a `local tokenlist`?

Comment: It's just a naming convention, `l` for local and `g` for global (and `c` for constant). I means: "I will never use `\tl_gset` on it; I wil stick to `\tl_set`." But nothing (technically speaking) stops you from doing `\tl_gset:Nn \l_no_tl_at_the_end_of_the_name:::____ {foo}`.

Comment: @yo In other words, what enables me to control the scope is the use of the `module` in those variable names. Got it.

Answer (score 4):

Apart from the bad naming scheme of your variables, the problem is in the misuse of `\seq_push:Nn` that should be instead

```
\seq_push:NV \l_neuwirth_aux_seq \l_neuwirth_aux_tl
```

and

```
\seq_push:NV \l_neuwirth_aux_seq \l_neuwirth_aux_tl
```

because you want to push *the contents* of the variable, not the variable. I used the “correct” variable names according to the declarations

```
\tl_new:N \l_neuwirth_output_tl
\tl_new:N \l_neuwirth_aux_tl
\seq_new:N \l_neuwirth_params_seq
\seq_new:N \l_neuwirth_aux_seq
\int_new:N \l_neuwirth_index_int
```

Full code. Note also

1. the naming of the internal function
2. `protected`
3. `\int_case:nn` instead of `\int_case:nnTF` with empty arguments
4. `~` for a space in output
5. `\seq_pop:NN` is to be preferred in case a sequence is used as a stack: the fact that the top is the “left side” should be of no concern.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\tl_new:N \l_neuwirth_output_tl
\tl_new:N \l_neuwirth_aux_tl
\seq_new:N \l_neuwirth_params_seq
\seq_new:N \l_neuwirth_aux_seq
\int_new:N \l_neuwirth_index_int

\NewDocumentCommand\myFunction{O{,} m}
 {
  \neuwirth_myfunction_build:nn {#1}{#2}
 }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \neuwirth_myfunction_build:nn #1 #2 
 {
  \tl_clear:N \l_neuwirth_output_tl 
  \seq_clear:N \l_neuwirth_params_seq 
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_neuwirth_params_seq { #1 } { #2 }
  \seq_pop:NN \l_neuwirth_params_seq \l_neuwirth_aux_tl
  \tl_use:N \l_neuwirth_aux_tl \\
  \seq_push:NV \l_neuwirth_aux_seq \l_neuwirth_aux_tl
  \seq_pop:NN \l_neuwirth_params_seq \l_neuwirth_aux_tl
  \tl_use:N \l_neuwirth_aux_tl \\
  \seq_push:NV \l_neuwirth_aux_seq \l_neuwirth_aux_tl 
  \int_set:Nn \l_neuwirth_index_int { 0 }
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \l_neuwirth_aux_seq 
   {
    \int_incr:N \l_neuwirth_index_int
    \int_case:nn {\l_neuwirth_index_int}
     {
      {1} {\tl_put_right:Nn \l_neuwirth_output_tl {##1,~}}
      {2} {\tl_put_right:Nn \l_neuwirth_output_tl {##1,~}}
      {3} {\tl_put_right:Nn \l_neuwirth_output_tl {##1,~}}
      {4} {\tl_put_right:Nn \l_neuwirth_output_tl {##1,~}}
     }
   }
  \mbox{contents~of~aux~sequence~after~two~pushes:~} \tl_use:N \l_neuwirth_output_tl \\
  \int_set:Nn \l_neuwirth_index_int { 0 }
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \l_neuwirth_params_seq  
   {
    \int_incr:N \l_neuwirth_index_int
    \int_case:nn {\l_neuwirth_index_int}
     {
      {1} {\tl_put_right:Nn \l_neuwirth_output_tl {##1,~}}
      {2} {\tl_put_right:Nn \l_neuwirth_output_tl {##1,~}}
      {3} {\tl_put_right:Nn \l_neuwirth_output_tl {##1,~}}
      {4} {\tl_put_right:Nn \l_neuwirth_output_tl {##1,~}}
     }
   }
  \mbox{contents~of~params~seq~after~two~pops:~} \tl_use:N \l_neuwirth_output_tl \\
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\noindent
\textbf{Function call:} \verb+\myFunction{1,2,3,4,5}+\\
\textbf{Disappointing result:} \\
\myFunction{1,2,3,4,5}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Contrary to what's said, the result should not be disappointing any more.

Actually, you're using the wrong method for displaying the sequences; here's some code that does the right thing:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\tl_new:N \l_neuwirth_aux_tl
\seq_new:N \l_neuwirth_params_seq
\seq_new:N \l_neuwirth_aux_seq

\NewDocumentCommand\myFunction{O{,} m}
 {
  \neuwirth_myfunction_build:nn {#1}{#2}
 }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \neuwirth_myfunction_build:nn #1 #2 
 {
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_neuwirth_params_seq { #1 } { #2 }
  \seq_pop:NN \l_neuwirth_params_seq \l_neuwirth_aux_tl
  \tl_use:N \l_neuwirth_aux_tl \\
  \seq_push:NV \l_neuwirth_aux_seq \l_neuwirth_aux_tl
  \seq_pop:NN \l_neuwirth_params_seq \l_neuwirth_aux_tl
  \tl_use:N \l_neuwirth_aux_tl \\
  \seq_push:NV \l_neuwirth_aux_seq \l_neuwirth_aux_tl 
  \mbox{contents~of~aux~sequence~after~two~pushes:~} \seq_use:Nn \l_neuwirth_aux_seq {,~}\\
  \mbox{contents~of~params~seq~after~two~pops:~} \seq_use:Nn \l_neuwirth_params_seq {,~}\\
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\noindent
\textbf{Function call:} \verb+\myFunction{1,2,3,4,5}+\\
\textbf{Expected result:} \\
\myFunction{1,2,3,4,5}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: On the topic of `\int_case:nn` vs. `\int_case:nnTF`: in actual practice I do want to do things if there are no parameters passed at all. Although wishing to avoid cluttering my MWE's with detail that has no relevance to the point I am trying to make, I will in future have to add a comment here or there to make things clearer.

Comment: One more thing still puzzles me: why are the items still in `\l_neuwirth_params_seq` despite being popped? If I pop them all I end up not with an empty sequence but one that contains the popped items in reverse.

Comment: @ReinhardNeuwirth You're popping and pushing them back. I'm not sure what you want to achieve with your `\seq_map_inline:Nn`, though.

Comment: (1) I am popping them from one (`params`) and pushing them onto the other (`aux`). And the manual says for `\seq_pop_left:NN` that the item is removed from the sequence once popped, as indeed one would expect from a stack. (2) the `inline` operations are there to see what is in those sequences, just for the purpose of this exercise. I am about to turn this little gadget into something really useful.

Comment: @ReinhardNeuwirth Your `\seq_map_inline:Nn` method doesn't display the sequences; I added a good method.